# Can I omit the type for make?

Tags: go

When making a slice or map...

```
type myType []map[string]someType

v = make(myType, 1)

v[0] = make(map[string]someType)
```

<sup>https://play.golang.org/p/Af9b0n0ykT</sup>

... I always have to specify the type twice. Can `make` not infer it?

This would be especially helpful when the type is an anonymous struct.

For example in Java the second mention of the type can be omitted:

```
HashMap<String, SomeType> v = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: No, you can't for anonymous struct.  but why not give a name to the struct?

Comment: Even if I gave it a name, I would still have to spell it out twice. Also, in a structure like that not every level has a meaningful name, which would lead to type names like `somewhatComplexTypeCMapEntryType`.

Comment: But you are right, my question isn't really about complex structs, I'll edit it.

Comment: I have edited the question so that it doesn't talk about complex structs anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. `make` requires a type as its first argument, and there are only two ways to specify a type: either as a name (eg: `myType`) or as a type literal (eg: `[]int`).

In principle, you can work around this using `reflect`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type someType struct{}

type myType []map[string]someType

func main() {
    var v = make(myType, 1)
    reflect.ValueOf(v).Index(0).Set(reflect.MakeMap(reflect.TypeOf(v).Elem()))
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

But this doesn't look like a good idea at all to me.

Comment: Indeed: `blah = reflect.MakeMap(reflect.TypeOf(blah)).Interface()` -> `cannot use reflect.MakeMap(reflect.TypeOf(blah)).Interface() (type interface {}) as type map[string]int in assignment: need type assertion`

Comment: OK, you can use `reflect` to do this -- not that it's a good idea. (I edited my answer).

Comment: Hm, would it be possible to wrap that into a function? No luck so far: https://play.golang.org/p/-j7g68V7g0

Comment: Yes, but you need to make the thing you're assigning to a pointer: https://play.golang.org/p/EPWtywAYaC . I don't recommend doing this at all though.

Comment: I kind of like it. ;) I think the zero value of a map should be an empty map anyway and I am seriously thinking of using this function in production code, perhaps naming it `FixMap()`. What is the downside, performance?

Comment: Yes, performance will be worse, but also you lose static typing in the code that uses `reflect`, and the code is difficult to read (and write -- as you discovered). Repeating the type doesn't seem nearly bad enough to me to warrant this kind of reflection-based workaround.

Comment: Actually I don't lose static typing at all, because the map variable still has its type, that's why I find it ridiculous that `make` needs to know the type *again*.

Comment: By losing static typing I mean that there's many ways to get the reflection code wrong without there being a compile-time error. You're right that your variable still has a static type. You say it's ridiculous that `make` needs to know the type, but the language is simpler with an explicit type argument, and that simplicity is worth something.

Answer (score -3):

with `type myType []map[string]someType` you define a **slice** of maps and it is different type

https://play.golang.org/p/rElNLx0H0S

```
package main

type someType int
type mymap map[string]someType
type myType []mymap 

func main() {
    v := make(myType, 1)
    v[0] = make(mymap)

    // HashMap<String, SomeType> v = new HashMap<>();
    var _ mymap = make(mymap)
}
```

runs totally fine

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? It just repeats my code example (with different names given to the types).

Comment: `make(mymap)` looks exactly like `new HashMap<>()`. whats the problem?

Comment: and btw there is no slice/array/list in your Java example, so yes, it is the answer to the question asked

Comment: Ah, now I'm starting to understand... you're saying that I can at least *shorten* the map definition by giving it a name? Well, yes, but I would still have to remember and type which name I gave it to actually initialize the map.

Comment: The slice is just there to make clear that I don't mean `v := make(map[string]someType) `. That is one case where the type name only has to be given once, but it doesn't work with slice elements.

Comment: 1) yes, when you did `HashMap<String, SomeType> v = new HashMap<>()` there are `HashMap` on both sides of assignment. And `var _ mymap = make(mymap)` has `mymap` as well (i'll update post with this example)
2) slice of elements is completely different type, because for compiler it has different memory layout. (example, int can be assigned to interface{} var; but []int can not be assigned to []interface{} var)